# How to make a reference between two integers in java?

Tags: java, reference

```
int x=1;
int y=x;
System.out.println(y);
x=20;
System.out.println(y);
```

Obviously the program will print 1 and 1.
However, I need to create a reference between x and y so every time i change x, y will be changed as well.

Comment: You need to create an instance of `Integer` instead of primitive int.

Comment: In Java world you achieve this little differently than C/C++ . Come back to your question once you understood the object orientation

Comment: @ashutosh What would that change?

Comment: @ashutosh `Integer` is an immutable class.

Comment: @ashutosh `Integer` isn't mutable, so that wouldn't help anything.  You need a wrapper class that can have its value changed, like [`AtomicInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html).